# Forwarding Twilio numbers

Tags: numbers, twilio, forwarding

I am still new to Twilio, and I was wondering if anyone knows how I can forward my Twilio phone numbers so that I can receive the calls in my office phone number?

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you have not put in any effort. Googling "twilio forward number" brought up instructions

Answer (score 2):

Jarod from Twilio. Essentially you'll just want to point your Twilio number's incoming Voice Calls URL to a new [TwimlBin](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) and inside that Twiml Bin you would then forward all calls by responding with the Dial verb, which just dials your office number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
   <Dial>
    +1-555-555-5813 
   </Dial>
 </Response>
```

Hope that helps!